# Trouble Installing Firefox

Tags: firefox

I've been trying to install firefox for Ubuntu today, and I cannot get it to work, i've tried using snap, and through normal terminal install but cannot get it to work.
If I just click the icon on applications nothing happens, but if I run it from the terminal I get this error,

```
Not loading module "atk-bridge" the functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: VA-API test failed: failed to initialise VAAPI connection.
ATTENTION: default value of option mesa_glthread overridden by environment.
```

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1
And the commands that I'm using are:

- $ sudo apt install firefox
- sudo snap install firefox

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: So your issue is not, in fact, installing Firefox, but in running it.

Comment: Can you try the following (non-snap) method instead? https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466

Comment: The question is unclear because Ubuntu desktop 22.04 comes with Firefox already installed as a snap. Is it a server?

Comment: `sudo apt install firefox` installs the snap by default on Ubuntu 22.04, it's a dummy package. Please add to the original question the output of  `snap list`.

Answer (score 1):

We can install Firefox in Ubuntu with five steps

Step 1: Remove the Firefox Snap by running the following command

```
sudo snap remove firefox
```

Step 2: Add the (Ubuntu) Mozilla team PPA to your list of software sources by running the following command in the same Terminal window

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
```

Step 3: Next, alter the Firefox package priority to ensure the PPA/deb/apt version of Firefox is preferred. This can be done using a slither of code from FosTips (copy and paste it whole, not line by line)

`echo ' Package: * Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam Pin-Priority: 1001 ' | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox`

Step 4: Since you’ll (hopefully) want future Firefox upgrades to be installed automatically

```
echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox
```

Step 5: Finally, install Firefox via apt by running this command

```
sudo apt install firefox
```

I Hope these steps will help you

SOURCE:[OMGUBUNTU][1]

[1]: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/04/how-to-install-firefox-deb-apt-ubuntu-22-04#:~:text=Installing%20Firefox%20via%20Apt%20(Not,reinstalled%20at%20a%20later%20date.